# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Loop on page load

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am having a problem getting Twitter Bootstrap Carousel to begin looping automatically at the required set timing rate when the page loads.

Anyone help point out what I am doing wrong please > http://phraseological.co.uk/ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the speed of the carousel by adding the following code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000
    })
  });
</script>
```

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

Remove line 289:

```html
<script src="./Phraseological SEO, SEO IS WHERE SEO IS HERE_files/jquery.js"></script>
```

Remove line 325:

```html
<script src="./Phraseological SEO, SEO IS WHERE SEO IS HERE_files/jquery.min(1).js"></script>
```

Remove line 326:

```html
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Remove line 328:

```html
<script src="./Phraseological SEO, SEO IS WHERE SEO IS HERE_files/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And it will works (tested)

Comment: Thanks for the help but sorry I know that part (I have it set at 6000) I think I worded the question badly/wrong, as, what I am trying to achieve is for the slide / carousel to begin automatically.  Presently it only begins to loop/slide once a person clicks on one of the navigation arrows and I want it to begin sliding without any manual action having to happen first EG for it to loop automatically after the page loads.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When I open the page with Chrome's Developer Tools, I get a resource error (404) for bootstrap.min.js.  Make sure you are including bootstrap's core js file properly.  The rest of the bootstrap plugins seem to be loaded in fine.

It may be related to when you are including certain things.  Make sure you are using the code snippet mentioned in the other question to make the carousel start automatically but only after the page/DOM has been completely initialized and thus the div.carousel element exists.

Comment: good point but all the plugin are loaded. bootstrap.min.js no more than the complete list plugin put all together and minified.

Comment: That's what I thought but I wasn't sure.  I've only been interacting with bootstrap through a rails gem that puts it in the asset pipeline haha.  I would recommend taking a look at the script that baptme mentioned below.  According to the docs (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) all you have to do is call .carousel() on the jQuery object referencing your carousel element on document ready and it should autoscroll.  I am using the carousel on a site I am writing and that is all I had to do to get it to autoscroll on page load.

Comment: I found where the problem come from (updated answer) +1 for helping me finding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To start the loop automatically you just have to add interval:true into your script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: true
    })
  });
</script>
```